# How to put border-radius on table header in table?

Tags: html, css, sass

My problem is I can't put a border radius in the table header part, what I did is I accessed the first child table row and then its `<td>`. But sadly it did not still worked. I have applied other solutions in stackoverflow but none was applied to my problem.Thank you in advance for the help.

Here is my code in HTML

```css
.event-list-container {
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  td,
  th {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ECE9F1;
  }
  tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  }
  tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  }
  tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  .color-light-black {
    background-color: #6F6680;
  }
  .text-align {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .icon-align {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="event-list-container">
  <table>
    <tr class="fs-14 graphik text-white color-light-black">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th class="text-align">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="fs-14 graphik-medium color-semi-black">1. Data 1</td>
      <td class="fs-14 graphik color-semi-black">16 Jun 2021</td>
      <td class="text-semi-gray icon-align">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" height="25" width="25" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path 
                    stroke-linecap="round" 
                    stroke-linejoin="round" 
                    stroke-width="2" 
                    d="M4 16v1a3 3 0 003 3h10a3 3 0 003-3v-1m-4-4l-4 4m0 0l-4-4m4 4V4" 
                    />
                </svg>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="fs-14 graphik-medium color-semi-black">2. Data 2</td>
      <td class="fs-14 graphik color-semi-black">16 Jun 2021</td>
      <td class="text-semi-gray icon-align">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" height="25" width="25" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path 
                    stroke-linecap="round" 
                    stroke-linejoin="round" 
                    stroke-width="2" 
                    d="M4 16v1a3 3 0 003 3h10a3 3 0 003-3v-1m-4-4l-4 4m0 0l-4-4m4 4V4" 
                    />
                </svg>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="fs-14 graphik-medium color-semi-black">3. Data 3</td>
      <td class="fs-14 graphik color-semi-black">16 Jun 2021</td>
      <td class="text-semi-gray icon-align">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" height="25" width="25" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path 
                    stroke-linecap="round" 
                    stroke-linejoin="round" 
                    stroke-width="2" 
                    d="M4 16v1a3 3 0 003 3h10a3 3 0 003-3v-1m-4-4l-4 4m0 0l-4-4m4 4V4" 
                    />
                </svg>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The actual table image I did

[image]

Comment: you should not nest classes in css

Comment: I hope this Will help you! https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2013

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Hi sorry, I used scss so that is why it is nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `first-of-type` selector you can apply styles to the first row that contains the headers and then a similar approach to find the first and last cells. It is the cells (th) that will have the border applied.

ie:

```
  /* explicitly target the first row and first th*/
  .event-list-container table tr:first-of-type th:first-of-type{
    border-radius:10px 0 0 0;
  }
  /* explicitly target the last th in first row */
  .event-list-container table tr:first-of-type th:last-of-type{
    border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
  }
```

```css
.event-list-container {

}
.event-list-container table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  /* explicitly target the first row and first th*/
  .event-list-container table tr:first-of-type th:first-of-type{
    border-radius:10px 0 0 0;
  }
  /* explicitly target the last th in first row */
  .event-list-container table tr:first-of-type th:last-of-type{
    border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
  }
  
  
.event-list-container td,
.event-list-container th {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  
.event-list-container tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ECE9F1;
  }
.event-list-container tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  }
.event-list-container tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }
.event-list-container tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  }
.event-list-container tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
.event-list-container .color-light-black {
    background-color: #6F6680;
  }
.event-list-container .text-align {
    text-align: center;
  }
.event-list-container .icon-align {
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="event-list-container">
  <table>
    <tr class="fs-14 graphik text-white color-light-black">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th class="text-align">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="fs-14 graphik-medium color-semi-black">1. Data 1</td>
      <td class="fs-14 graphik color-semi-black">16 Jun 2021</td>
      <td class="text-semi-gray icon-align">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" height="25" width="25" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path 
                    stroke-linecap="round" 
                    stroke-linejoin="round" 
                    stroke-width="2" 
                    d="M4 16v1a3 3 0 003 3h10a3 3 0 003-3v-1m-4-4l-4 4m0 0l-4-4m4 4V4" 
                    />
                </svg>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="fs-14 graphik-medium color-semi-black">2. Data 2</td>
      <td class="fs-14 graphik color-semi-black">16 Jun 2021</td>
      <td class="text-semi-gray icon-align">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" height="25" width="25" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path 
                    stroke-linecap="round" 
                    stroke-linejoin="round" 
                    stroke-width="2" 
                    d="M4 16v1a3 3 0 003 3h10a3 3 0 003-3v-1m-4-4l-4 4m0 0l-4-4m4 4V4" 
                    />
                </svg>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="fs-14 graphik-medium color-semi-black">3. Data 3</td>
      <td class="fs-14 graphik color-semi-black">16 Jun 2021</td>
      <td class="text-semi-gray icon-align">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" height="25" width="25" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path 
                    stroke-linecap="round" 
                    stroke-linejoin="round" 
                    stroke-width="2" 
                    d="M4 16v1a3 3 0 003 3h10a3 3 0 003-3v-1m-4-4l-4 4m0 0l-4-4m4 4V4" 
                    />
                </svg>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I little bit rearranged your css code but it worked for me :)